# Escape regex special characters for tr1::regex

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

I need to **embed user-input in my regular expression**, so it needs to be escaped for any regex special characters, and I don't know in advance what the string will be.

It would be something like

```
string pattern = "\\d+ " + myEscapeFunction(userData);
```

Which special characters do I need to escape? Or is there an equivalent function to Qt's [QRegExp::escape](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qregexp.html#escape)?

Comment: I'm not sure, if there is a generic solution, because it depends on the expression standard. For example (AFAIR) some engines required ] to be escaped and some didn't. You should look at your standard's rules of escaping strings and do some string replacements...

Comment: That would seem to be the case. Now that I think about it, tr1::regex allows the expression standard to be set at runtime. I think it defaults to ECMAscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of characters that you have to escape depends on which of the various regular expression grammars you're using. If you're using the default `ECMAScript`, it looks like the list in the `QRegExp::escape` documentation is a good place to start. It says:

> The special characters are $, (,), *, +, ., ?, [, ,], ^, {, | and }.

That list leaves out `\` for some reason.

But it's slightly more complicated than that, because inside square brackets, none of the characters except `\` and `]` are special, and `\]` has to stay unescaped.

Further, a `?` that comes right after a `(` is not special. For example, in `(?=x)` the `?` should **not** be escaped.

I think that's pretty much it, but I haven't put enough time into this to be sure.